# Android kotlin widget: where to initialise and to store state

Tags: android-widget

I'm trying to write a home screen widget. (As usual developer.android.com is useless.) The lifecycle seems to be completely different to an `Activity`; is this documented anywhere?

Every so often I want to get a new value, add it to the list of previous values, and update the widget.

Where is the state stored and how is it initialised?

I've got

```
class CurrentCurrentWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private lateinit var batteryManager: BatteryManager
```

but I don't understand how to set `batteryManager` because there is no `onCreate`.

I've tried

```
  if(batteryManager == null) {...}
```

all over the place which is very unsatisfactory.

And what is `onEnabled`? What does *enabled* mean? Ditto *disabled*? Again: the lifecycle is obviously completely different -- and undocumented.

I set a breakpoint in my `onUpdate` but doesn't get hit. What do I need to do to make it run? I was under the impression that this will just get called periodically according to `android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"`, but apparently not so.

Is any of this documented?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no way to maintain state between calls of `onUpdate`.

Therefore I have made a class -- a bit like a viewmodel -- to hold the required values and which loads itself from `SharedSettings` at the start of `onUpdate` and saves itself at the end.

This seems unsatisfactory.

Should I be using a `Bundle`?